# CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK gets called immediately when dialled

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am trying to get the event when call is picked up. I search and found that CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK should be used for this. However this does not works. This state is called as soon as number is dialled. This is my code:

```
@Override
     public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
         if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
             // phone ringing
             // But this gets called as soon as number is dialled.
             endCall();

         }
         if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
             // active
             phoneCalling = true;          

             new CountDownTimer(MyApplication.GetData().getDuration()*1000, 1000) {
                 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {           
                 }
                 public void onFinish() {
                    endCall();
                 }
              }.start();
         }
         // When the call ends launch the main activity again
         if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
             MyApplication.GetData().setIsReturnedFromCall(false);

             if (phoneCalling) {
                 phoneCalling = false;
             }
         }
```

Comment: So this is for outgoing calls? The behavior you describe sounds right. `OFFHOOK` is an analogy to old phones where you'd lift the handset off an actual hook switch or similar construction. You'd have to lift the handset off the switch before dialling a number.

Comment: So what's the solution for this ?

Comment: And yes, this is for outgoing calls. Not tested for incoming. State will perhaps behave the same way there as well.

Comment: As far as I know there's no way for an app to get information about when the person at the other end of an outgoing call picks up.

Answer (score 0):

I found it was due to my `call recorder` app, `uninstalling`, and `reinstalling` made no difference. I had to go into settings, then apps, click on the app, and storage, followed by `clear data`. This resolved the issue.